# Having issue publishing React Native android expo

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eebSv.png)

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
> e: /Users/bishalaryal/Documents/Github/rushlaundry/Frontend/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/tasks/BundleHermesCTask.kt: (138, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I have tried changing the gradle version and also reinstalled java. Nothing seems to work. I am using M2 pro.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you need at least Gradle 7.6 to fix this. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36246